# Erro no Módulo PagSeguro em Loja Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

Boa tarde,

Instalei em minha loja Magento o módulo PagSeguro, mas não consigo finalizar a compra, pois recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.colorbox is not a function
```

Estou recebendo este erro na linha 91, do arquivo pagseguro-module.js. Segue o trecho do código:

```
var open = function(o) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({},defaults,o || {});
    if( options.inline && options.avoidDefault ){
        if( !options.width && !options.innerHeight ){
            options.innerWidth = parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css('width').replace('px','')) + parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css( 'padding-left' ).replace('px','')) + parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css( 'padding-right' ).replace('px',''))
        }
        if( !options.height && !options.innerHeight  ){
            options.innerHeight = parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css('height').replace('px','')) + parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css( 'padding-top' ).replace('px','')) + parseInt(jQuery( options.href ).css( 'padding-bottom' ).replace('px',''));
        }
    }
    jQuery.colorbox(options);
};
```

Procurei por alguma solução no site do desenvolvedor, mas sem sucesso. Inclusive, achei outro post por lá com o mesmo problema, sem solução.

Uma das dicas que obtive dizia para eu desabilitar alguma extensão que poderia estar causando o conflito. Eu uso todas as extensões instaladas, que são pouquíssimas.

Jquery não é meu forte, por isso solicito ajuda dos gurus!

Agradeço antecipadamente!

Comment: Acessando o código fonte pelo navegador, consegue confirmar se o arquivo jquery.colorbox-min.js está sendo renderizado?

Comment: Amigo, obrigado por tudo, mas abri mão deste módulo, decidi ir para o checkout transparente. Estou tendo outro problemas, mas vou gerar um outro tópico. Grande Abraço!

Comment: @FelipeAssunção, acabei voltando. O PagSeguro não dá suporte, vou te falar, uma dor de cabeça tremenda. Enfim, olhei o código fonte, há referência dele sim no `<head>`. O problema está na função. Estou pesquisando, mas essa linguagem não é meu forte, definitivamente. Ainda estou estudando, por força da necessidade. E agora? Estou perdido!

Comment: A loja em questão, caso queira dar uma olhada é: http://donachicosa.com.br

Comment: Teste com cliente anonimo e foi normalmente você mudou a integração?

Comment: Pois é, amigo. Esse pessoal do Pagseguro é muito "paia". Baixei o módulo do Ricardo Martins, tive erros no início, mas os resolvi. O problema é que tem uma mensalidade de R$ 9,90 para Boletos e Transferências Bancárias. Enfim, o Cartão de Crédito está 100% resolvido, já fiz diversos testes, e você também... rs... Obrigado pela boa vontade e pelo suporte, desta forma nossa comunidade fica cada vez mais forte! Abraço e sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Veja se você fez referência do arquivo de jQuery.colorbox após o arquivo jquery.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```